Laravel Filament - Hide resource actions on reorder
I have a project that includes a custom Laravel Filament CMS. In this CMS i have a resource that contains some actions like view/edit/delete defined in my table(Table $table) method in the resource:
$table
    ->reorderable('sort_index')
    ->actions([
        Tables\Actions\ViewAction::make(),
        Tables\Actions\EditAction::make(),
    ])

These actions are properly displayed on the end of each entry of this resource

The issue I am facing is that when I reorder the resource entries using the reorder button on the top right, it hides both the action buttons and the pagination controlls. After some time I figured out i can stop the pagination from hiding using ->paginatedWhileReordering() however there does not seem to be any similar method for having the actions while reordering.
Is this even possible without making an entire wrapper around the table view, just for the action buttons to show? and if not, what would be the easiest way to make such a wrapper?
Thanks in advance!
